# In the Lagrangian, do we add or subtract terms from the objective function?

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Are there two accepted definitions of the Lagrangian?

Most of the time, I have seen the Lagrangian of an optimization problem defined as the objective function **minus** a bunch of terms related to the constraints. However, the version below from *Convex Optimization* by Boyd/Vandenberghe seems to define a totally different function. Surely the addition of the terms (rather than their subtraction) is not a typo by the authors?

[image]

Comment: $\lambda$ can take a positive, zero or negative value so it makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the optimization itself, the sign doesn’t matter – as noted in a comment, $\lambda_i$ can have either sign anyway, and also the constraint $f_i(x)=0$ could be multiplied by $-1$ without changing the problem.

There’s one reason, however, that I learned about only recently (after decades of applying Lagrange multipliers) to use a particular sign. If you have a constraint of the form $f(x,y)=b$, then if you introduce the Lagrange multiplier in the form $L(x,y)=u(x,y)-\lambda f(x,y)$ you can interpret $\lambda$ as $\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm db}$ (where $u(b)$ is the optimal value of $u$ given the constant $b$ in the constraint). The first-order stationarity conditions are

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\lambda\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0\;,\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-\lambda\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0\;,
$$

and this yields

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm db}
&=&
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm db}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm db}
\\
&=&
\lambda\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm db}+\lambda\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm db}
\\
&=&
\lambda\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm db}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm db}\right)
\\
&=&
\lambda\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm db}
\\
&=&
\lambda\;.
\end{eqnarray}

So if $b$ is some sort of budget you can spend on $x$ and $y$ (for instance with $f(x,y)=xp_y+yp_y$, where $p_x$ and $p_y$ are the prices per unit of $x$ and $y$), then $\lambda$ tells you how much your utility $u$ increases when your budget increases. This is used a lot in economics. Obviously it doesn’t work if you use the other sign.

Comment: Is the interpetation of lambda the same when minimizing an objective function? In other words, would we continue to say that lambda is "how much your utility u increases when your budget increases"?

Comment: @artist_and_not_EE_by_training: Well you wouldn't call a function you're minimizing "utility", and $b$ probably wouldn't play the role of a "budget" – but other than that, yes, $\lambda$ would still measure how much the objective function increases when the parameter $b$ increases – whatever the interpretation of the objective function and the parameter $b$ might be in that case. The direction of optimization (minimization or maximization) doesn't affect the derivation of $\frac{\mathrm d u}{\mathrm db}=\lambda$; what matters for that are only the relative signs of $u$, $\lambda$ and $b$.

Comment: Wonderful explanation, thank you joriki